# cppwinrt A subclass of Panel (or other class)，What constructors are needed？

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm sorry my English isn't very good.
I have a class like this

```
   struct WrapPanel :winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::PanelT<WrapPanel>
   {
   public:
       WrapPanel(std::nullptr_t) {};
       // other code.....
   }
```

Use in other classes

```
    WrapPanel wrapPanel{ ItemsPanelRoot().try_as<WrapPanel>()};
    //Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'WrapPanel'
```

like：
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/move-to-winrt-from-cx
Converting from a base runtime class to a derived one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you author a runtime class in C++/WinRT, you'll get several classes with the same name in different namespaces. Let's suppose that there's a namespace named `NS1`, in which there's a runtime class called `WrapPanel`, you'll get `winrt::NS1::WrapPanel`, `winrt::NS1::implementation::WrapPanel` and `winrt::NS1::factory_implementation::WrapPanel`. The first one is the "projection" of the runtime class, which we usually use; the second one is the "implementation", which implements the runtime class; the third one is the "factory", which is used by `module.g.cpp`.

If you convert a base class to a derived one, you should use the "projection". It seems that you have used the "implementation".

Comment: thanks, I am use *.idl file   like this
namespace NS1
{
 [default_interface]
 runtimeclass WrapPanel : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Panel
 {
  WrapPanel();
                ....
 };
}

Comment: It would be fine to change your code to NS1::WrapPanel wrapPanel{ ItemsPanelRoot().try_as<NS1::WrapPanel>()};